# Deep Relationships with Trashed Records in Laravel 5.1 Eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

The relationship is defined as follows:

```
Apples hasMany Grapes hasMany Bananas hasOne Pineapple
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
$apple = \App\Apple::find(1);
$pineapples = $apple->pineapples
```

And I have somewhat achieved this by defining the following in `Apple.php`

```
public function pineapples(){
  $apple = $this;
  return Pineapple::whereHas('banana', function($banana) use ($apple)
  {
    $banana->whereHas('grape', function($grape) use ($apple)
    {
      $grape->where('apple_id', '=', $apple->id);
    });
  })->get();
}
```

However there is the added complication that some of the `Banana` records could be soft deleted (trashed). Is it possible for me to more elegantly get all the `Pineapples` that are distantly related to an `Apple`? Is it also possible to include those that are "blocked" by trashed records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a scope and lazy eager loading.

`Pineapple.php`

```
public function scopefromApple($query, $appleId = 1)
{
    $query->join('bananas', 'bananas.id', '=', 'pineapples.banana_id')
        ->join('grapes', 'grapes.id', '=', 'bananas.grape_id')
        ->join('apples', 'apples.id', '=', 'grapes.apple_id')
        ->where('apples.id', '=', $appleId);
}
```

This allows me to use `\App\Pineapple::fromApple()` successfully. In the case that I then need to include trashed `Banana` records:

```
$pineapples = \App\Pineapple::fromApple();
$pineapples->load([
    'banana' => function ($query){
        $query->withTrashed();
     }
]);
```